# Trigger action via button

Tags: ajax, actions

I am using `wordpress 4.9.8` and `PHP 7.1.8` I have added a button to the new post screen:

[image]

I am trying to trigger the button the following way:

```
add_action( 'media_buttons', 'add_my_media_button', 99 );
function add_my_media_button() {

    $post = $GLOBALS['post_ID'];
    echo "<a href='#' id='insert-my-media' data-post-id='{$post}' class='button'>Own content</a>";

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'updateContent' );
function updateContent() {

    $post_id = intval( $_POST['post_id'] );

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
    $post = array(
        'ID'           => $post_id,
        'post_content' => 'Insert this content',
    );

    // Update the post into the database
    wp_update_post( $post );
}

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_media_button_script' );
function my_media_button_script() {

    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#insert-my-media').click(function () {
                var post_id = $(this).attr('data-post-id');
                var data = {
                    'action': 'updateContent',
                    'post_id': post_id
                };
                console.log("test: " + ajaxurl)
                console.log(data)
                // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <?php
}
```

However, when pressing submit I get:

[image]

Any suggestions why I get this error.

The above code was partly taken from the official [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'updateContent' );
```

Add this two Line

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_updateContent', 'updateContent' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_updateContent', 'updateContent' );
```

hopefully it will solve your issue

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)

Comment: Could you update your answer with an example?

Comment: Sure I will update my answer as soon as I can

Comment: Code Example added ! @Howdy_McGee thanks .

Comment: @Ahadul Thanks for your answer & update, +1

Answer (score -1):

Replace this
**add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'updateContent' );**

with

**add_action( 'wp_ajax_updateContent', 'updateContent' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_updateContent', 'updateContent' );**

Happy codeing